# I want to show integer while using write function

Tags: c, integer

1) I need to create a function that displays the number entered as a parameter. The function has to be able to display all possible values within an int type variable.

2) and prototype should be like `void ft_putnbr(int nb);` this way

### Here is my code,

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    write(1, &nb, 1);
}

int     main()
{
    ft_putnbr(42);
}
```

---

And the result was not integer numbers, it's just like.. asciicode
It showed "*"

What's wrong with my code? Can you correct my code? or suggest more appropriate way?

plus) int main function will be given automatically, so I just have to make prototyped function

Thanks for your help

Comment: `printf("%d\n", nb);`

Comment: @yano Can you show it without using printf ?
use write function

Comment: you'd do better with `write(1, &nb, sizeof nb);`. Barring niche cases, `int`s will be multibyte, you've told it to just write 1 byte. However, an `int` is binary data and printing that raw probably isn't what you want. You should convert your `int` to a string first using something like [`sprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) . Also note that using `write` isn't a common way of printing to `stdout`, `printf` and `puts` are far more common. I assume you have some assignment stipulation to use `write`, if that's not the case just use `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is not working as expected, is because you passing an integer when you supposed to passing a pointer to the write function and the last argument of write should be the length of what you writing to the file descriptor (standard output in your case).

Here is an explanation of C pointers that may help you understand how to use them

https://boredzo.org/pointers/

Here are some resources on the write function.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/POSIX_Reference/unistd.h/write

http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:write

You need to treat as a string before using write, so you could convert it to a string before had or print it digit by digit

Here is how you could approach it

```
void ft_putnbr(int n) {
  char * const str_num = itoa(n);
  const size_t len = strlen(str_num)
  write(1, str_num, len);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a string representation of the number, otherwise you're printing the binary.

```
void ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
   char nbuf[16];
   const int len = snprintf(nbuf, sizeof nbuf, "%d", nb);
   write(1, nbuf, len);
}
```